# Count unique cells in a column or row of an HTML table with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, unique, cells

Is there a simple way to count the unique cells in a column (or row) in an HTML table with jQuery or plain Javascript?

Example: (table with only one column)

```
melon
banana
melon
strawberry
```

The counter would be 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var a = {}, l = 0;
$('table tr td:first-child').each(function(){
    if (!a[$(this).text()]) {
        l++;
        a[$(this).text()] = true;
    }
});

alert(l);
```

For HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>melon</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>banana</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>melon</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>strawberry</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

This will work for first column. If you want to count values in second column you would use selector `table tr td:first-child+td`, for third `table tr td:first-child+td+td`, etc.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/7K64j/1/

Comment: +1 This method is more efficient than the one i posted as it uses array indices for matching and thus eliminates the need for array traversal.

Comment: @TimDown I didn't realize that. I've switched to `$(this).text()`.

Comment: The link mentioned above is helpful

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var matches = [];
$('table td').each(function() {
  if(!$.inArray($(this).text(), matches)==-1) matches.push($(this).text());
});
alert(matches.length);
```